# Trying to Learn C++, Tic Tac Toe program not working

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to learn C++ and I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe program. I'm really confused and it's late, but I just want to figure out what is going wrong so I can feel like I accomplished something. Any help would be great. Here's the full code not working at all. Thanks!

http://codepad.org/fuC4JxBE

These are the errors I get:

```
Description                                  Resource     Path           Location    
expected primary-expression before ']' token    main.cpp    /Tic Tac Toe    line 47 C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ']' token    main.cpp    /Tic Tac Toe    line 56 C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ']' token    main.cpp    /Tic Tac Toe    line 57 C/C++ Problem
expected primary-expression before ']' token    main.cpp    /Tic Tac Toe    line 62 C/C++ Problem
```

I honestly I have no idea why I'm getting these errors. I searched around to see what the error usually means but it seemed like non of the other problems were similar.

Comment: isolate *one* problem, ask about that, include the relevant code, expected result and actual result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler error tells you anything you need to know. Add a `,` in line 82 after `char whoWon`

*edit* regarding your new problem: you cannot pass multidimensional arrays like that. <strike>Remove the `3` in those brackets and the `numCols` in the declarations/definitions. If you really need to pass the array size, you need to pass it differently, e.g. as another argument.</strike> I take that back. I guess you have to put a constant in when passing multidimensional arrays. (In the definition/declaration)

Comment: Yep, that red sign tells you that the (first) error is somewhere there. 99% of the time it's in that line or the previous one.  When compiling, always try to find and correct the **first** error the compiler finds.